# use numpy iterator for validation data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tfrecord

I am new to machine learning and i am trying to solve a problem with my code.
The training dataset I am using is saved in a `tf.record` file and since it is too large to be stored in memory I am using an iterator for the training set. The problem is that even the validation set is too big to put into memory (at least for my laptop with only 2GB of memory on the video card), so it is saved on disk as a `tf.record` too, I just don't think I can use the same trick as the iterator. What can I use then?

Code

```
#reading training and validation dataset
def read_tfrecord(example):
  tfrecord_format = (
      {
          "x": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
          "y": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
      }
  )
  example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, tfrecord_format)
  x = tf.io.parse_tensor(example['x'], out_type=tf.float32)
  y = tf.io.parse_tensor(example['y'], out_type=tf.double)
    

  return x,y

filename = "train.tfrecord"
training_dataset = (tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename).map(read_tfrecord))
iterator = training_dataset.repeat().prefetch(10).as_numpy_iterator()

filename = "validation.tfrecord"
validation_dataset = (tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename).map(read_tfrecord))
val_iterator = validation_dataset.repeat().prefetch(10).as_numpy_iterator()
```

I call then fit method in this way

```
model.fit(iterator,
          validation_data=(val_iterator),
          epochs=35,
          verbose=1)
```

but the program fails to finish the first epoch, it stucks and never ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution using generator, I'll post the code

```
#generator
def generator(self, dataset, batch_size):
      ds = dataset.repeat().prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
      iterator = iter(ds)
      x, y = iterator.get_next()
      
      while True:
        yield x, y

#reading training and validation dataset
def read_tfrecord(example):
  tfrecord_format = (
      {
          "x": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
          "y": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
      }
  )
  example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, tfrecord_format)
  x = tf.io.parse_tensor(example['x'], out_type=tf.float32)
  y = tf.io.parse_tensor(example['y'], out_type=tf.double)
    

  return x,y

filename = "train.tfrecord"
training_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename).map(read_tfrecord)
train_ds = generator(training_dataset, batch_size)

filename = "validation.tfrecord"
validation_dataset = (tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename).map(read_tfrecord))
valid_ds = generator(validation_dataset, batch_size)

kwargs['validation_data'] = (valid_ds)

#get your training step with something like this
training_steps = x.shape[0]//batch_size
validation_steps = x_val.shape[0]//batch_size

model.fit(train_ds, steps_per_epoch = training_steps, validation_steps=validation_steps, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure as to why you want to use your 2GB video card instead of a colab or Kaggle notebook. But hope this helps

```
valid = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_valid, y_valid))
valid = valid.batch(batch_size)

model.fit(iterator,
          validation_data=valid,
          epochs=35,
          verbose=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for the help you are giving me, the program should run on a local machine. However my fault, I badly explain the problem, I changed the question. Also the validation set is loaded from disk from a tfrecord file since it is too big to load into memory, using the same trick of the training set the program does not terminate, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't know how else you can make it work. Try to have a look at [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/mixed_precision). This will decrease your memory consumption by the model.

Answer (score 0):

When your dataset doesn't fit into your memory you should for sure split it into batches, that way you only load a subset of your dataset to memory at a time. Also, I don't know how large are your data samples but prefetching also affects your memory usage, using `.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` can be beneficial since the buffer size is tuned dynamically.

```py
# tune this value experimentally
batch_size = 32

training_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename).map(read_tfrecord)
training_dataset = training_dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

filename = "validation.tfrecord"
validation_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename).map(read_tfrecord)
validation_dataset = validation_dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

```py
model.fit(training_dataset, validation_data=validation_dataset, ...)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this gives me `ValueError: Cannot iterate over a shape with unknown rank.`